# python "@" cause SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

pyrapl:
https://pypi.org/project/pyRAPL/

```
import os
import pyRAPL

pyRAPL.setup() 
csv_output = pyRAPL.outputs.CSVOutput('result.csv')

command = "stress -c 4 -t 10"

@pyRAPL.measure(output=csv_output)

os.system("stress -c 4 -t 10")

csv_output.save()
```

python rapl_log.py

output:

```
  File "/home/edison/Downloads/rapl_log.py", line 11
    os.system("stress -c 4 -t 10")
    ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix this problem? I think that may caused by the "@" in "@pyRAPL.measure(output=csv_output)", but I am new to python~.

I hope to use pyrapl to log the energy value for run "stress".

Comment: What did you do to find out how the `pyRAPL` library worked?

Comment: Why did you type a `@` there?

Comment: `@` use to define decorators over a function. you need to write a function below the `@` line statement

Comment: Decorators are used at definition of a function - not on call of a function like you are doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @ symbol is used for [decorators](https://peps.python.org/pep-0318/), which modify functions, so you need to wrap your code in a function.  Perhaps this modified version of your code would work:

Example slightly modified from the [docs](https://pypi.org/project/pyRAPL/):

```
import pyRAPL

pyRAPL.setup()

csv_output = pyRAPL.outputs.CSVOutput('result.csv')

@pyRAPL.measure(output=csv_output)
def foo():
    # Instructions to be evaluated.
    os.system("stress -c 4 -t 10")

for _ in range(100):
    foo()

csv_output.save()
```

Comment: It works(although the DRAM part of PyRAPL report some error, I think that is because PyRAPL have some problem with my CPU).